# Python scikit learn's TfidfVectorizer - max of 1.0?

Tags: python, nltk, tf-idf

I couldn't find the answer to this online, but are the results of tfidfVectorizer.fit_transform an array with **max value of 1.0**?

Because, with 
`idf(term_i)= 
log (#number of docs/ number of docs containing term_i )`, shouldn't idf, and subsequently tfidf, be > 1.0 in many cases?

i.e. Documents containing the word 'absinthe'. Say our term freq (tf) is 1, but idf is (1000 total documents/ 1 document containing 'absinthe') = 1000, 1*1000 = 1000, no?

But in my cases of using scikit-learn's TfidfVectorizer, the max value I get seems to be 1. Is it normalized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the tfidf rows are L2 normalized. [Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a95203b/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1024) is the critical line in the source code.

```
if self.norm:
        X = normalize(X, norm=self.norm, copy=False)
```

`normalize()` comes from the sklearn.preprocessing module, where it indicates that it normalizes the rows by default. [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html#sklearn.preprocessing.normalize) is the link to the `normalize()` docs.